# How to format time with PHP for specific output

Tags: php, date, formatting

I am trying to format last modified timestamp for all pages, but need to get it in specific format.

This is how it should look: `2014-04-26T15:58:45+00:00`, but all my attempts are either ended with error or just like that `2014-04-28 13:41:49`

here is my variable `date($info['sitemap_last_modified']);`

I was also trying to use the following `date(DATE_ATOM, mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 1, 2000));`, but I do not know where to place the following `$info['sitemap_last_modified']`

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the `c` modifier for the PHP [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

```
// Assuming $info['sitemap_last_modified'] is in a 
// standard format strtotime() can parse
// http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php
echo date('c', strtotime($info['sitemap_last_modified']));
```

Comment: It worked, just fine, but this is how it looks now 2014-04-28T13:41:49+02:00, shouldn't it be 2014-04-28T13:41:49+00:00??

Comment: You need to account for timezones

Comment: OK, so if my timezone is GMT and server is in London?

Comment: I would expect it to be +00:00. Doublecheck to make sure your server is set up with that timezone. `echo date('c');`

Comment: this is what I have 2014-04-28T15:25:14+02:00

Comment: Doesn't sound like the timezone is set to what you think it is. You can change it in your script, though. Look into [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) or use DateTime() with DateTimeZone().

Comment: I will change the server timezone, I think it would be much easier